# array of mappings throwing while execution

Tags: solidity

So I'm refactoring a solidity contract and am trying something i'm not sure it works, but it should as it's compiling but throwing in the constructor while deploying.

It goes a little something like this:

```
contract MyContract {
    struct UserStruct {
        bool isExist;
        uint id;
        uint referrerID;
        uint referredUsers;
    }
      
    mapping (address => PoolUserStruct) [] poolUsers;
    mapping(uint => address) [] poolUserList;
    uint[] public poolCurrentUserID = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
    
    constructor {
        PoolUserStruct memory pooluserStruct;

        for(uint i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
          poolCurrentUserID[i]++;

          pooluserStruct = PoolUserStruct({
            isExist: true,
            id: poolCurrentUserID[i],
            payment_received: 0
          });

          poolActiveUserID[i] = poolCurrentUserID[i];
          poolUsers[i][msg.sender] = pooluserStruct;
          poolUserList[i][poolCurrentUserID[i]]=msg.sender;
        }
    }
}
```

it is breaking on each of the last two lines in the for loop.

Is what i'm trying to do even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your first mapping that points to a struct `PoolUserStruct` which is never created in the contract, the struct I can find in your code is `UserStruct`.

Secondly, contructors in solidty are defined like so `constructor() public{}`

Try changing these and tell me if you still have an error, I'll be happy to help.